# Sitefinity 4 - MasterPages

Tags: master-pages, sitefinity, sitefinity-4

I am running the trial version of Sitefinity 4 RTM.

The great thing about Sitefinity 3.x was that I could port my masterpages from an existing site and they would just work with Sitefinity:  Sitefinity did not inject stuff into the pages, or the content blocks.

However, Sitefinity 4 seems to be injecting its own stuff (styles, etc) into the page that screw up my layouts.

Also, for example the Sitefinity ContentBlocks wrap their content in a

tag.

Is there a way to stop this happening or would I have to rewrite my master pages and style sheets if using Sitefinity 4?

Other issues, eg, setting up a new site are great, but the above is a bit of a killer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll probably want to post this to the [Sitefinity forums](http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums.aspx).  You'll get a lot more attention there.

--

However, here are a few thoughts:

1. Check out the Design and Skin settings for Sitefinity Widgets.  By default, Sitefinity Widgets get associated with a Sitefinity Skin and some embedded stylesheets.  By switching to a custom skin, you can define your own CSS.
2. Feel free to modify the templates being used by Sitefinity widgets.  You can define your own HTML.

I'm doing a webinar next week (Real World Project Development with Sitefinity 4.0) that will touch on some of these things.  For those visiting here later, the video can be found on [Telerik.TV](http://tv.telerik.com/).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks the reply, am subscribed to the webinar.  My issue is that I have always just designed the masterpages for the overall site, then reused them in the CMS area of the site.  This strategy doesn't seem to work so neatly in SF4, so really need to know what I have to do to keep a consistent look and feel between standard pages and Sitefinity pages... and how much more work this represents.  I can see that the new layouts eliminate the need for nested masterpages, which is great, but is my base design that is giving me problems.  Also, the trial version won't run the Charity SDK...

Answer (score 0):

Once you integrate master page from an existing site, no need to add  attribute block in the child page, provide only the body part. sitefinity by default generates  attribute.
Here is a link for documentation on how to use custom CSS. Hope this will be helpful:
https://docs.sitefinity.com/custom-themes-and-templates-create-the-css-of-the-theme